# How do I pipe the files downloaded with wget through tar?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, tar, wget

I would like to pipe tarballs (`.tar.gz` files in this case) I download with GNU Wget (`wget`) through `tar -xzf` (to decompress them, if this is unclear)  but I don't know how. I have tried:

```
wget -q -O- ${SRC_URI} | tar -xzf > ${DESTDIR}
```

and

```
wget -q -O- ${SRC_URI} | `tar -xzf` > ${DESTDIR}
```

and

```
wget -q -O- ${SRC_URI} | 'tar -xzf' > ${DESTDIR}
```

not one even came close to doing what I want. I have also tried omitting the output component `> ${DESTDIR}` and just letting tar to extract the tarball's contents the way it does by default. Each attempt usually either returned an error like:

```
tar: option requires an argument -- 'f'
```

before it would download the tarball, or nothing but then I would check for whether the path set by `${DESTDIR}` had been created (as I was leaving tar to generate it) and it had not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you're extracting a tar.gz file from stdin, you don't need to specify the `f` option, `tar` defaults to reading from stdin.

Assuming you want to extract the contents to $DESTDIR, you also need to use GNU `tar`'s `-C` (change directory) option.

I've also put `"` quotes around the variables, in case $SRC_URI or $DESTDIR contain any spaces or shell meta-characters - `&`, `*`, `?` and the like.

Finally, the `{}` curly braces around the variables aren't strictly necessary here, but I've left them in anyway - they certainly don't cause any harm.

Putting that all together, you get:

```
wget -q -O- "${SRC_URI}" | tar -xz -C "${DESTDIR}"
```

Comment: And you might want to run `mkdir "${DESTDIR}"` before the command so the `-C` can effectively change to that directory: `mkdir -p "${DESTDIR}" && wget -q -O- "${SRC_URI}" | tar -xz -C "${DESTDIR}"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `-` as the 'file' to extract. The `wget` command outputs to STDOUT (`-O-`) and tar needs to use STDIN as input file: `tar zxf -` to extract.