# save tar stdout to files using pipelines

Tags: ssh, tar, stdout, stdin

I try to download a archive to a remote computer using SSH and also extract the archive on the remote client due to it having better performance.

I have a very simple script that downloads the archive and then uses `tar xjOf` via ssh on the remote client to extract the files. I now want to pipe the output of the tar command to some process that can save the extracted files on the local client. I think tar should have that ability, but I'm not able to find any solution.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1@$2 'wget https://url.to.my/archive.tar.bz2' #Save the archive to the remote client
ssh $1@$2 'tar archive.tar.bz2 -xjOf' | ??? #What local tool can be used to take the output and save the files from it?
```

I'm rather new to Linux and shell-scripting so the code will probably have lots of ways to improve, but for now I just want to know how to save those files to my local client.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Partly (but not completely) a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239741/how-do-i-pipe-the-files-downloaded-with-wget-through-tar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download and decompress the archive on the remote machine, but extract the files on the local machine, you could do this like so:

```
you@local ssh <remote> "wget -qO - https://url.to.my/archive.tar.bz2 | bunzip2" | tar x
```

What happens here is this:

1. You execute the commands within quotation marks on the remote machine. So the downloading and decompressing happens on the remote machine.
2. The output of this command is piped to tar on your local machine and is extraced locally.
3. This also means - as Andre Beaud and yourself point out - that the uncompressed data is transferred from remote to local via ssh. This leads to a tradeoff between time gained from the faster uncompression remotely that may outweigh the time lost on network traffic between remote and local.
4. The good thing however is that the decompressing is done *while* it's downloading from the url on remote.

A few things to notice here:

1. Your script is here a single command line. This command uses the ability of ssh to execute a command on a remote computer *right away* and return the output to your local computer.
2. As always you have to read the documentation to know if a command can read (standard input) and/or write (standard output) a stream of data and how to instruct the command to do this.

   - Wget can and the dash (-) after -qO instructs wget to write to standard output (stout).
   - Bunzip can as well and if no file is given takes input from stin and writes to stout.
   - Tar takes it's input from stin by default as well.
3. Also the file format needs to support streaming data. Both the tar and bzip2 formats do, but not every format does. (zip for example)
4. In this case wget gets two parameters. The first -q option (quiet) is added to wget to turn off the output of log and error information so it's not part of the data stream read by tar. The second -O is analogous to shell redirection and - as said - the dash (-) after this instructs wget to write to standard out.
5. This output is piped to bunzip2. Bunzip2 does not need any additional instruction if the stream of data is piped to bunzip2. Hence the bunzip2 command can just follow the wget command.
6. What bunzip2 also can is accept a tar archive as input and decompress it's contents. Hence no additional steps in between are needed.
7. The whole of wget and bunzip2 is made into the command parameter for ssh using quotation marks.
8. The output of this whole is then piped to tar on the local machine. Again, because tar takes input from stin by default, no additional options but the extract option.

Extra:
In my earlier answer I didn't understand the question completely. I left it here for those who want to download and extract an archive on a remote machine from your local machine, the most efficient way to do this is this:

```
you@local ssh <remote> "wget -qO - https://url.to.my/archive.tar.bz2 | tar xj"
```

In the example above the files are extracted in your home directory on the remote computer in same the directory structure as they were put in the tar. You could change that - *to an existing folder on remote* - with something like:

```
you@local ssh <remote> "wget -qO - https://url.to.my/archive.tar.bz2 | tar xjC <destination/dir>"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailled answer and explenation, however the idea is, that the archive is downloaded and extracted on the remote machine, but the extracted files are saved to the local machine. As Andre Beaud mentioned, this is of course a bit silly since the bottleneck would then be the network, however this is the task at hand that I need to solve.

Comment: Clear Lumnezia, I have edited the answer to address this.

Comment: @Lumnezia is there some reason why you can't run `tar` on the local system?

Comment: @muru in the answer above you do run tar on the local system: you@local ssh <remote> "wget -qO - https://url.to.my/archive.tar.bz2 | bunzip2" | tar x

Comment: @acw sure, but that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need the tar to run locally; tar -O basically `cat`'s the file contents only so is not suitable to recreate the files from. You can run the bunzip2 remotely to take advantage of a fast remote cpu - just remember that all the data is now uncompressed when it gets sent back to the local machine, so you might lose any time you saved from faster decompression, if bandwidth becomes the limiting factor. Try both ways and see! Anyway, after the wget..

```
# do the bunzip2 from the ssh, then pass the output to (local) tar to extract the files on the local system:
ssh $1@$2 'bunzip2 < archive.tar.bz2'|tar -x
```

Answer (score 1):

Decompressing an archive with `tar` goes like : -x=extract, -j=decompress-with-bz2 and -f=filename. You would thus write

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1@$2 'wget https://url.to.my/archive.tar.bz2'
ssh $1@$2 'tar -xjf archive.tar.bz2'
```

This is a bit risky since `wget` might save your file as another name, like `archive.tar.bz2.1' if a file with the same name already exists. Use` wget -O fixedname.tar.bz2 ...` for a deterministic output.

Note that 'tar' is a streaming format (unlike zip), which allows you NOT to store the archive and uncompress it on the fly - uses less disk space and IO operations :

```
ssh $1@$2 'wget -O- https://url.to.my/archive.tar.bz2 |tar -xj'
```

Note that I removed the '-f' since there is no filename, data flows from the wget before the 'pipe'. Some stuff will still be printed on your terminal via stderr, try `wget -qO-` for a quieter operation if you like. Note that if errors happen they will still be printed, but only if they happen. That's the Unix mantra : if everything goes fine, just don't mention it.